# Why doesn't enabledelayedexpansion work with pipelined commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to use a Windows batch file to run a command, pipe its output to another command, and capture the exit status of the first command.  But apparently, I can't do that, although I'll grant that Windows batch files are so arcane that I may have missed a technique.  **How can I both capture the exit status of a command and pipe its output?**

It's the classic `do_a_thing | tee logfile.txt` usage, but I want to be able to check whether `do_a_thing` succeeded or not.  After lots of fooling around, googling, and reading StackOverflow, I came up with the following:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set rc=-1
( false & set rc=!errorlevel! & echo rc=!rc! ) | tee logfile.txt
echo %rc%
```

Which I had hoped would produce:

```
C:\>test.bat 
C:\>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
C:\>set rc=-1 
C:\>(false & set rc=!errorlevel!   & echo rc=!rc!  ) | tee logfile.txt
rc=1 
C:\>echo 1
1
```

But, alas, it did not:

```
C:\>test.bat
C:\>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
C:\>set rc=-1
C:\>(false & set rc=!errorlevel! & echo rc=!rc! ) | tee logfile.txt
rc=!rc!
C:\>echo -1
-1
```

Removing the "`| tee logfile.txt`" produces the expected value of `!rc!`, but of course, it doesn't let me capture the log file.

```
C:\>test.bat
C:\>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
C:\>set rc=-1
C:\>(false & set rc=!errorlevel! & echo rc=!rc! )
rc=1
C:\>echo 1
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to to do does not work because each side of the pipe is executed in its own command shell in a command line context with delayed expansion off by default. See [Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/1012053) for more info. The accepted answer explains everything, and the other answers help give context to the accepted answer.

The easiest solution is to write the error code to a temp file and then read the file into a variable after the command has completed.

```
( false & call echo %%^^errorlevel%%>returnCode.txt ) | tee logfile.txt
set "rc="
<returnCode.txt set /p "rc="
del returnCode.txt
echo rc=%rc%
```

The CALL statement provides another level of parsing that occurs after the command has run. The trick is to delay the expansion OF %errorlevel% until after the command you are testing has run. In a command context you can simply use `CALL ECHO %^ERRORLEVEL%`. But the command line must also pass through a batch context parse before it reaches the command context, so the percents must be escaped as `%%` and the caret as `^^`.

Comment: **OK, now that's cool** (or at least as cool as batch files can get).  I never knew that CALL could call a batch command like ECHO.  All the documentation (_e.g._, [for WinXP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true)) says only `.BAT` or `.CMD` files and/or `:labels`.

Comment: I knew about the separate shells, and all the implications, and I had previously tried writing `!errorlevel!` to a file and reading it back, but the `call echo %%^^errorlevel%%` was the magic I was looking for.  It works beautifully!