# What is %0|%0 and how does it work?

Tags: windows, command-line

If you run a .bat or .cmd file with `%0|%0` inside, your computer starts to use a lot of memory and after several minutes, is restarted. Why does this code block your Windows? And what does this code programmatically do? Could it be considered a "bug"?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

This is the Windows version of a [**fork bomb**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

`%0` is the name of the currently executing batch file. A batch file that contains just this line:

```
%0|%0
```

Is going to recursively execute itself forever, quickly creating many processes and slowing the system down.

This is not a bug in windows, it is just a very stupid thing to do in a batch file.

Comment: Why does %0|%0 break windows, but %0 does not?

Comment: @Pavel: What a `.bat` file does is: read instruction, at the end of file terminate. If you run %0:
Process 1: starts, run %0 (thus create process 2); then die
Process 2: starts, run %0 (thus create process 3); then die
[...] you alway have at most 2 process running because the creator will die.

The point of fork bomb is to create 2 version. Thus P1 create 2 process (1' and 1"), those two process will create, each, 2 (thus 4), going exponential.

Answer (score 41):

This is known as a fork bomb.
It keeps splitting itself until there is no option but to restart the system.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb

Comment: @RohanGala: `$0; $0` (works in bash and zsh, tested on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Note that you can stop it with ⌃C, you'll need to ignore SIGINT or detach to prevent that. (:

Comment: :(){ :|:& };: is one version

Comment: `./$0 | ./$0 &` works as well as a bash script.

Answer (score 33):

## What it is:

`%0|%0` is a **[fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)**. It will spawn another process using a pipe `|` which runs a copy of the same program asynchronously. This hogs the CPU and memory, slowing down the system to a near-halt (or even crash the system).

## How this works:

`%0` refers to the command used to run the current program. For example, `script.bat`

A pipe `|` symbol will make the output or result of the first command sequence as the input for the second command sequence. In the case of a fork bomb, there is no output, so it will simply run the second command sequence without any input.

Expanding the example, `%0|%0` could mean `script.bat|script.bat`. This runs itself again, but also creating another process to run the same program again (with no input).

Answer (score 11):

%0 will never end, but it never creates more than one process because it instantly transfers control to the 2nd batch script (which happens to be itself).

But a Windows pipe creates a new process for each side of the pipe, in addition to the parent process. The parent process can't finish until each side of the pipe terminates. So the main program with a simple pipe will have 3 processes. You can see how the bomb quickly get's out of control if each side of the pipe recursively calls the parent batch!

Comment: How is the second part of the pipe called if the first recursive call never returns?

Comment: The two sides are run asynchronously

Comment: I was told that the pipeline calls the second half with the return of the first half: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/win32/win32scripting.html#Win32Scripting-Command-Redirection-And-Pipelines

Comment: There is good info about the asynchronous nature of Windows pipes here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194279/1012053

Answer (score 6):

It's a logic bomb, it keeps recreating itself and takes up all your CPU resources. It overloads your computer with too many processes and it forces it to shut down. If you make a batch file with this in it and start it you can end it using taskmgr. You have to do this pretty quickly or your computer will be too slow to do anything.