# Split a string with a word for delimiter in batch

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, cmd, set

I need to split a string in a batch file using a word for delimiter.

For example if I have an input like :

```
C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\File.c
```

I'd like to split it considering the word "Dir2" so that I get in output :

```
Dir2\Dir3\File.c
```

Note that the number of parent/children directories of Dir2 cannot be known before processing.

I've tried with `for /f` but it does not work as it does not accept delimiters with several characters but only single characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split string without for loop in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620709/how-to-split-string-without-for-loop-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET string=C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\File.c
SET divider=Dir2
CALL SET after=%%string:*%divider%=%%
CALL SET before=%%string:%divider%%after%=%%
ECHO before=+%before%+
ECHO divider=+%divider%+
ECHO after=+%after%+
GOTO :eof
```

Test output:

```
before=+C:\Dir1\+
divider=+Dir2+
after=+\Dir3\File.c+
```

`+` was included simply to demonstrate that there are no stray spaces involved.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
set "word=C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\File.c"
set "word=%word:*C:\Dir1\=%"
echo %word%
```