# Windows - Batch File string manipulation

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, split

Again, I'm struggling with Batch files on **windows**, and again I hope you can help me again. I don't understand a thing of it ;)

I now have the following code that prints the name of the underlying directories when the directory contains 'R1' in its name.:

```
FOR /d %%d in (directory\*R1*) do (
SET x=%%d && echo %x%)
```

I now have the directory name as a string, set in 'x'. I want to split this string on the \ and get the last item. Then I want to replace 'R1' with 'R2' in that last item. Can anyone make a function for me that works? I'm lost.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620709/how-to-split-string-without-for-loop-in-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /d /R %%d in (.\*R1*) do (
 SET "x=%%~nxd"
 SET "x=!x:R1=R2!"
 IF /i not "!x!"=="%%~nxd" ECHO old : "%%d" new : "%%~dpd!x!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should do what you want. The `/R` switch on the `FOR` means "and subdirectories, too", and I changed your `directory` to `.` for my testing.

Since you don't appear to say what to want to do with the strings, I've simply echoed to old and new versions.

The `if` statement will filter out only those directories that have `R1` somewhere in the last "leaf" of the directory tree.