# How to split string with "=" without for loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file, split, substitution

I would like split a string in two part with `=` as delimiter.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620709/how-to-split-string-without-for-loop-in-batch-file) but I do not manage ta adapt.

I try this:

```
set "str=4567=abcde"
echo %str%
set "var1=%str:^=="^&REM #%
echo var1=%var1%
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: because its an equal sign which is special character when it comes to string replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As npocmaka commented above, `=` has special meaning and cannot be replaced with traditional variable string manipulation.  If you know the length of either side of the equal sign, you could strip off a number of characters.  For example, if "4567" will always be 4 characters, you could `set "var1=%str:~0,4%"`.  Or if "abcde" will always be 5 characters, you could `set "var1=%str:~0,-6%"` (5 chars + 1 for the equal sign).

Otherwise, a `for` loop is your only other option without using 3rd party utilities.

```
for /f "delims==" %%I in ("%str%") do set "var1=%%I"
```

If you've got [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) installed, you can do something like:

```
echo %str% | grep -P -o "^[^=]*"
```

... but you'd still need to capture its output with another `for /f` loop.

If you are allergic to `for` loops, and as an exercise in providing a solution to your question without any regard for efficiency, here's how you get the first half of your string without using a single `for` loop.  Put `grep` and its dependencies in your `%PATH%`.  Then:

```
echo %str% | grep -P -o "^[^=]*" >temp.txt
set /P "var1="<temp.txt
del temp.txt
echo %var1%
```

There, I fixed it!

Comment: That's a different question entirely.  You should post it as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

While not a bulletproof solution (*use the `for`, artoon*), without more info, this can do the work

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "str=4567=abcde"

    rem Step 1 - remove the left part
    set "str1=!str:%str%!"

    rem Step 2 - Get the right part
    set "right=!str:*%str1%!"

    rem Step 3 - Get the left part
    set "left=!str:%right%=!"
    set "left=%left:~0,-1%"

    echo [%left%] [%right%]
```

**edited** to adapt to comments (OP code in comments adapted to my code, or the reverse)

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('set') do ( 
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Step 1 - remove the left part
    set "str=%%i"
    for %%x in ("!str!") do set "str1=!str:%%~x!"

    rem Step 2 - Get the right part 
    for %%x in ("!str1!") do set "right=!str:*%%~x!" 

    rem Step 3 - Get the left part 
    for %%x in ("!right!") do set "left=!str:%%~x=!" 
    set "left=!left:~0,-1!" 

    echo [!left!] [!right!] 
    endlocal
)
```

And no, as previously indicated this is not bulletproof and some of the variables show problems (had I said it is not bulletproof?).

What i don't understand is the requirement to not use a `for` loop and then use a `for` loop. It is a lot easier this way

```dos
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set') do (
    echo [%%a] [%%b]
)
```

Another alternative (not as easy as the `for`, more stable than the previous one, non bulletproof) is

```dos
    for /f %%a in ('set') do (
        call :split left right %%a
        echo [!left!] [!right!]
    )
    goto :eof


:split leftVar rightVar data
    set "%~1=%~3"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "data=%*"
    set "data=!data:*%1 %2 %3=!"
    set "data=%data:~1%"
    endlocal & set "%~2=%data%"
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Yes, it works but how use it in loop for ? I tried this : for /f "delims=" %%i in ('set') do (
 rem Step 1 - remove the left part
 set "str1=!%%i:%%i!"

 rem Step 2 - Get the right part
 set "right=!%%i:*%str1%!"

 rem Step 3 - Get the left part
 set "left=!%%i:%right%=!"
 set "left=%left:~0,-1%"

 echo [!left!] [!right!]
)

Comment: @artoon, answer updated. And, as you are using a `for` loop, i have also included a code with a `for` loop to do the same work with less problems

Comment: @artoon, one more added.