# Windows piping simple issue

Tags: windows, cmd, piping

I want to do this:

```
echo < test > | more
```

This didn't work, so I tried this:

```
echo ^< test ^> | more
```

This didn't work either

What am I doing wrong?

PS.: I need the brackets to be printed. They part of the string I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how pipes are implemented by Windows CMD.EXE, the ECHO statement gets parsed twice, so the special characters must be escaped twice.

```
echo ^^^< test ^^^> | more
```

See [Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/1012053) and all the answers for an in depth discussion of the many non-intuitive features of pipes.

Answer (score 1):

More doesn't correctly parse escaped string, you need to go through some hops.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ("^< test ^>") do echo %a | more
```

Comment: That is a fine solution, but the explanation is incorrect. MORE has no problem processing `<` and `>` characters. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22673717/1012053) for a more accurate explanation.