# Batch Pipe blocks the Source

Tags: c++, multithreading, batch-file, pipe

*First of all: I would like to read and handle the output of a game console with my external, so I will be able to write some new feature for the game server.*

My problem is that, I redirected the output of the `Source` to the `Mod` via batch pipe this way:

```
.\Source.exe | Mod.exe
```

**Mod.exe** (for test now):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line, '\n')) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the pipe does not seem to be async.

*I mean I am not able to connect to the server until the `Mod` does not finish writing the lines from its STDIN. And if I connect to the server after waiting the `Mod` flushing its content, I am able to make the server lagging with writing lot of things to chat (make the `Source` console filled with data)*

**So the `Source` stoppes, if the pipe has too much data unhandled by the `Mod`**

I have found this about this here: [Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192318/why-does-delayed-expansion-fail-when-inside-a-piped-block-of-code)

> **Asynchronously is not the full truth**
>
> I said that the both threads are asynchronous, normally this is true.
>   But in reality the left thread can lock itself when the piped data
>   isn't consumed by the right thread. There seems to be a limit of ~1000
>   characters in the "pipe" buffer, then the thread is blocked until the
>   data is consumed.

It is problem because the `Mod` can have slowly executable content later, and it can make the `Source` unavailable/lagged. (This is why I tested it delayed)

Is there any other way to make the `Source` to not wait `Mod` to get all contents? (I use C++ for the mod)

Comment: Uhhhm what?? What ever would you expect to happen asynchronously in the code sample you gave?? Do you have some serious misunderstandings? You might be interested looking into e.g. [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) and [`pipe()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) documentation.

Comment: I don't know how pipes work. I just want to handle the gameserver's output line by line. This code is async until about 1000 bytes as the quote told, then the Main thread locks itself. I need a non-blocking pipe or something that works like it is desired. As I know, fork() does not work on Windows. I tried CreateProcess, but it was not successful for me as well.

Comment: Try some POSIX compatible API for windows like [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to get `fork()`/`pipe()` working; or even higher level abstractions as provided with [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Just using the standard input/output handles with your program doesn't help out for your problem. Certainly `Sleep(1000);` doesn't cure anything (you don't have asynch IO there actually!).

Comment: Sleep(1000); wants to represent how slow the mod could be after I create that later :)

Comment: _'Sleep(1000); wants to represent ...'_ bad choice probably :P ...