# How to pass multiple values in a single variable using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to pass multiple values in a variable. Here's my code

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set "content="

for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.txt) do (
  set "content=!content!%%x!LF!" 
  Type paul.txt  | findstr /I /V /C:"!content!" > edit.txt
)

echo(!content!

PAUSE

endlocal
```

Basically, this code opens the file file.txt and the contents of this file were used and pass to variable "content".

Example:

file.txt contains the ff:

```
A
B
```

So, all lines starting A or B on file paul.txt will be removed but no lines were removed. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch! You are going about this completely wrong. First I will list some errors. Then I will show you a very simple solution.

1) There is no need to place all the lines in a single variable. Each line represents an independent search term. Putting all lines (including linefeeds) in a variable and using that in `/C:string` option treats the entire content as a single search term that tries to match the file content with the entire term, including the linefeeds.

2) Even if you really did want all lines in a single variable, your logic is wrong. You are executing your FINDSTR upon each iteration, but you only want to execute it once after the variable is completely populated.

3) The delayed expansion is not working as you expect because you are attempting to use it with a pipe - the value is getting expanded too early. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194279/1012053.

4) You state you want to exclude lines that ***begin*** with the file content. You need to instruct FINDSTR accordingly.

5) Not an error, but there is no need to use a pipe at all. Simply let FINDSTR read paul.txt directly.

And the simple solution:

```
findstr /viblg:file.txt paul.txt >edit.txt
```

Note that I have concatenated the FINDSTR options after a single `/`. This is one of many [undocumented FINDSTR features](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053).

The `/G:file` option instructs FINDSTR to use each line within file as an independent search string.

The `/L` option forces the search strings to be interpreted as literal strings (as opposed to regular expressions)

The `/B` option forces the search terms to only match the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the job in your situation?

```
findstr /r /i /v /c:"^A" /c:"^B" file.txt >file2.txt
```

Comment: Yes but I want the file contents to be used

Comment: Your code will give you two copies of `paul.txt` inside the file and neither of them will be missing all lines that start with A or B.

Comment: contents of files.txt will be used to remove lines in paul.txt. Then once removed, edit.txt will be the final file

Comment: You don't follow what I said.  See Dave's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /l /v /g:file.txt Paul.txt > edit.txt
```

Find the non matching lines in `Paul.txt`, reading search strings from `file.txt`, sending the output to `edit.txt`

If the match needs to be over the full line, include a `/x` in the list of arguments