# Cannot set argument value to a variable resulting empty in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm looping through all command-line arguments using `SHIFT`. I'm getting result of `ECHO is off.`. It is likely printing the empty variable.

```
:argLoopStart
    SET paramName=
    SET arg=%1
    IF -%arg%-==-- GOTO argLoopEnd
    IF %arg:~0,2%==-- (
        SET paramName=%arg%
        ECHO %arg%
        ECHO %paramName%
    ) 
    SHIFT
    GOTO argLoopStart
:argLoopEnd
```

By running the command `fake-command --dbs=mydbname`, I got this:

```
--dbs
ECHO is off.
```

According to the code above, `ECHO %arg%` prints `--dbs` and `ECHO %paramName%` prints `ECHO is off`. The line of `SET paramName=%arg%` is not working as I expected. `%parameName%` should print `--dbs` as well. However, it seems printing an empty variable.

Comment: Why are you expecting `%paramName%` to be `--dbs` and not `--dbs=mydbname`?

Comment: `--dbs=mydbname` is equal to `--dbs mydbname`. `=` is ignored by  the compiler. As you see, `%paramName%` should be same as`%arg%` which is printing `--dbs` because of the line `SET paramName=%arg%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable delayed expansion with `SETLOCAL` [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) at the top of your script:

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution
>   time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the
>   SETLOCAL command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables may be
>   referenced using !variable_name! (in addition to the normal
>   %variable_name% )

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:argLoopStart
set paramName=
set arg=%1
if -!arg!-==-- goto argLoopEnd
if %arg:~0,2%==-- (
    set paramName=!arg!
    echo !arg!
    echo !paramName!
)
shift
goto argLoopStart

:argLoopEnd
```

Comment: `EnableDelayedExpansion` is already at the top of my script. The code I mentioned is just a part of the whole script. Anyway, can you please explain why it is needed?

Comment: You still need to replace the `%` with `!` in order for it to work. As for _why_ it works, I'm not entirely sure, as I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of batch. That said, your code is acting in a similar manner to a `for` loop, which needs delayed expansion enabled for variable values inside of it to update with every loop iteration.

Comment: @sithu: Please post all significant parts of your script. Guessing games become boring after about the five thousandth time. Please search SO for `delayed expansion` for hundreds of articles explaining why the `!var!` syntax - or `call %%var%%` is necessary. Why are you invoking `enabledelayedexpansion` if you evidently don't know why it's used?

Comment: @Magoo There are just a few lines (3 or 4 lines) of `SET` for other variables before this block of code. I'm coding those argument processing at the topmost possible. Adding explanation about `EnableDelayedExpansion` in the answer would increase the quality of the answer, right? It is sad that you did not think like that.

Comment: @Sithu I've been looking for an explanation for why delayed expansion is needed that is better than "because it won't work otherwise," and I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194279/4158862) by Jeb that suggests that `set` commands inside of parentheses blocks need it in order to be processed at the correct time.