# Why is there no need for `call` to return from called batch script which is involved in a pipe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe, call

Supposing there is a batch file (caller) which executes another batch file (callee), the `call` command needs to be used in order to return to the caller after the callee finishes execution. Here is an example:

**`caller.bat`:**

```
echo Calling another script...
call callee.bat
echo Returned from callee...
```

**`callee.bat`** (in the same location)**:**

```
echo   Being called from caller...
```

The output will be this (omitting the command echos), showing that execution returned as expected:

> ```
> Calling another script...
>   Being called from caller...
> Returned from callee...
> ```

If the `call` command was dismissed in the caller, the output would be:

> ```
> Calling another script...
>   Being called from caller...
> ```

---

But as soon as the callee is involved in a pipe (`|`), there is no difference in whether or not the `call` command is used. For instance:

**`caller.bat`** (the callee remains unchanged)**:**

```
echo Calling another script...
break | callee.bat
echo Returned from callee...
```

The output will be this, although there is no `call` command.

> ```
> Calling another script...
>   Being called from caller...
> Returned from callee...
> ```

What is the reason for this behaviour, what causes execution to return to the caller here?

Comment: The question for me is there any difference between `break|command` and `call command` ? Check also this `set a=b` ; `set b=c` ; `break|echo %%%a%%%`  . And... the output is `c`  .In both cases you create a new sub-context of the cmd. May be some states  of the cmd preserved when `call` is used ?

Comment: Oh. `REM` , `IF` and `FOR` behave different when are piped and when are CALLed but this is rahter die to the parsing.

Comment: Hmm... besides data transfer of _STDOUT_ to _STDIN_ of pipes, there seems to be no difference at all; even `cmd /C callee.bat` returns to the caller; yes, `rem`, `if` and `for` are special, because I remember they are recognised earlier than other commands during the parsing process...

Comment: I think it has to do with the way cmd parses stuff, first parsing the entire line, and then executing the piped commands, effectively parsing them a second time.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194279/5022761

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are *two ways* to call another Batch file from the caller one (*main* file): `call callee.bat` and `cmd /C callee.bat`; the difference is that `call` execute the other Batch file *in the same context* of the caller program, so they share the same environment variables and another status, whereas `cmd /C` execute the other Batch file in an entirely separated context. Just as a personal note, I used to name *internal subroutine* the Batch file invoked via `call`, and *external subroutine* the one invoked via `cmd /C` (and *overlay* the Batch file directly invoked without `call` nor `cmd /C`, that *inherits* the behavior and context of the caller Batch file).

In the execution of a pipe, both sides of the pipe are executed via a `cmd /C`, so both sides are invoked as external subroutines. This way, if any side of a pipe is a Batch.BAT file, it returns to the caller program when it ends.

The same behavior happen in a callee Batch file placed in a `for /F` command, and exaclty for the same reason; `for /F %%a in ('calle.bat') do ...`