# Why don't Windows Shell (cmd.exe) builtin commands read from stdin?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, windows-shell

Why don't Windows Shell (cmd.exe) built-in commands read from stdin? (or so it seems)

Example:

```
echo bar | set /p foo=
```

Comment: `set /p` by itself _does_ read from stdin. It's just getting piped input in that example.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192318/why-does-delayed-expansion-fail-when-inside-a-piped-block-of-code/8193124#8193124) first and then, the whole topic...

Answer (score 3):

SET /P does read the input from the pipe, but it doesn't do any good because both sides of the pipe are executed within new cmd.exe processes. So the newly defined variable is lost once the pipe sub-processes terminate.

For more information, see [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194279/1012053) to the Stack Overflow question - [Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/1012053)