# windows batch - ECHO is changing the %ERRORLEVEL%

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo, errorlevel

I have the following .bat snippet

```
echo about to start echoing, Errorlevel=%Errorlevel%

echo. >> ../time.txt

echo Just echod a new line into time.txt, Errorlevel=%Errorlevel%

echo | set/p=start=%time%, >> ../time.txt    

echo about to start with emake, Errorlevel=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

The output is:

```
about to start echoing, Errorlevel=0
Just echod a new line into time.txt, Errorlevel=0
about to start with emake, Errorlevel=1
```

Why is the line `echo | set/p=start=%time%, >> ../time.txt` changing the `%ERRORLVEL%`?

Comment: It's not `echo`; it's `set`command  wrong syntax; use `echo | set/p start=%time%, >> ../time.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That lines sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 because `SET /P` fails (sets ERRORLEVEL to 1) whenever it fails to set a value, and your `set/p=start=%time%,` will never set a value. Everything after the first `=` is considered to be the prompt, so there is no variable, and the command will always "fail".

I have no idea what you are attempting to do with that line, so I can't give you a solution. But one thing you should be aware of - [SET /P is useless for setting variables if used within a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37816932/1012053).

Comment: I'm not trying to set anything. Rather, I use that construct - from a stack post - to be able to `echo` without newlining.

Comment: I fixed the %ERRORLEVEL% via `echo | set /p start=%time%, >> ../time.txt` and it still outputs on same line as I need it to.