# Using !ERRORLEVEL! in code block piped to another process

Tags: windows, batch-file, exit-code, errorlevel

Why the `!ERRORLEVEL!` does not work in the following example?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  winscp.com /?
  echo !ERRORLEVEL!
) | findstr /v "word"
exit
```

I get `!ERRORLEVEL!` on the output.

While if I remove the `| findstr /v "word"`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  winscp.com /?
  echo !ERRORLEVEL!
)
exit
```

I get the error level on the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because a pipe executes both sides in new cmd.exe instances (when the command is a batch command).

The commands/code blocks are converted and used as parameters for cmd.exe, in your example it becomes:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /S /D /c"( winscp.com & echo !errorlevel!)"
```

But as a new cmd.exe instance is invoked, the delayed expansion is disabled by default.

You could also examine the behaviour by using the `cmdcmdline` pseudo variable.

```
@echo off
(
  echo %%cmdcmdline%%
  echo !ERRORLEVEL!  
) | findstr /n "^"
```

Shows:

> 1:C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" ( echo %cmdcmdline% & echo !ERRORLEVEL!  )"
> 2:!ERRORLEVEL!

For more information [Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/463115)

**Using errorlevel inside a code block with piping**

You could simply use another expansion method

```
(
  winscp.com /?
  call echo %%ERR^^ORLEVEL%%
) | findstr /v "word"
```

Obviously, this works by the fact, that the converted block looks like

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" ( winscp.com /? & call echo %ERR^ORLEVEL%  )"
```

After cmd.exe parsed the block the percent expansion is already done and the block looks like

```
( winscp /? & call echo %errorlevel% )
```

The caret is important here, to avoid that the expansion occurs before the line is executed.

**Another solution**

Create your own cmd.exe instance with delayed expansion enabled by

```
(
  winscp.com /?
  cmd /V:on /c echo !SOME_VARIABLE!
) | findstr /v "word"
```

But this only works with "normal" variables, NOT with `ERRORLEVEL` or `cmdcmdline`, because they are changed by starting the new instance

**Using a sub batch file**

Instead of using a code block on the left side of the pipe, you could use a batch file, there it's possible to enable the delayed expansion again.

I'm using a trampoline function, to put the complete code into one batch file.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%X in ("%0") do goto :%%X

"%~d0\:myblock:\..\%~pnx0" | findstr /v "word"
exit /b

:myblock
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  winscp.com /?
  echo !ERRORLEVEL!
)
exit /b
```